# ccavenue check out without billing information

Tags: payment-gateway, ccavenue

i m doing ccavenue integration in php. my whole code is working wekk with the help of billing details. 
my question is :-
Can i use ccavenue integration without giving billing details successfully? if yes then how? 
i mean i should not need to give customer billing details. but when i use without billing details then it shows error given below.

**Security Error.** Illegal access detected

order_id    123654789
tracking_id 303000076347
bank_ref_no null
order_status    Invalid
failure_message 
payment_mode    null
card_name   null
status_code 
status_message  Please enter a name with min. 3
max. 60 characters., 21010:billing_tel: Required parameter missing., 31011:billing_email: Invalid Parameter

thanx in advance.

Comment: have you solved this issue?@ Mayank Raichura I have checked CCAvenue, those parameters are required fields. I have one doubt, There are so many website which uses CCAvenue or other payment gateways which are not required Billing address etc How they manage?. Let me know your suggestions.

Answer (score 7):

Yes you can do it, just follow below steps:

- Drop a mail at risk@ccavenue.com that you want to hide billing
  address from your ccavenue account.
- Don’t forget to mention your  register URL and Merchant Id on that
  mail.
- Within 3 to 4 hours you can do your ccavenue check out without
  billing information.
- you can also contact them at [**CCavenue Support **](https://login.ccavenue.com/web/contactUs.do?command=navigateContactUs)

**However we need to post billing country and customer details(ie contact number and email id) to CCAvenue checkout page through backend mode.
Also note, as we have skipped billing information from the CCAvenue checkout page, International payment options cannot be offered.**

Answer (score -1):

IMHO, billing details are required to verify the card details provided by the user.

Payment Gateway will pass that information to the bank/credit card processor which will intrun validate the details against it's internal database. Should the validation fail, it will fail the transaction as happened with you.

Therefore, irrespective of the delivery address, the billing name / address should match the name and address provided to the bank during issuance of the debit/credit card.